# S ◦ R : duplicate relations?

Tags: matrices, relations

$R$ = $\{(2,1),(2,2)\}$

$S$ = $\{(1,2),(2,2)\}$

$S \circ R$ = {(2,2),(2,2)}

Is the answer then {(2,2),(2,2)} or {(2,2)}
I couldn't find anything about removing duplicates relations, 
but it makes more sense that way. Especially when put in a matrix.

Unless this is allowed

$S \circ R$ =
            $\begin{bmatrix}
            0   &   0  \\
            0   &   2  \\
        \end{bmatrix}$

Comment: You write only $(2,2)$.

Comment: My method is then, to get all the relations.
And then remove the duplicates?

Or should i be checking if it exists already, if it does, don't write it?

Comment: You remove the duplicates. Its like when you have a set, name $A=\{x\}$. You can write $A=\{x,x\}$ but is redundant.

Comment: Okey thanks.
My math book only had examples without any chance of duplicates, so when it happened that I got duplicates I wasn't sure what the correct answer was :)